# ToolTip didn't show on MS Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two questions about the tooltip.

1. I add the tooltip on the button, but it didn’t show.

   ```
   <Button Content=">" Name="btn_2" Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="2"  Grid.RowSpan="4" ToolTipService.ToolTip="updated"></Button>
   ```
2. Can I add the tooltip on ApplicationBarIconButton? If so, would you give me a sample or link .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add the tooltip per se, but you can try simulating doing something like this:

http://igrali.com/2012/01/07/show-a-tooltip-for-tapped-pushpin-on-windows-phone/

This uses contextmenu from the Silverlight for Windows Phone toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

1. No tooltips on a phone (any phone)
2. See 1